# Class not available in namespace after build

Tags: c#

I have a VS solution set up using build scripts to copy the compiled DLL into another project. The base project builds fine, and copies correctly to the target.

However, the target project won't compile as it can not find a particular class within the namespace:

**foo.cs**

```
namespace foo {
    public class bar {
        public static string myVar {
            get { return "A string"; }
        }
    }
}
```

**myPage.aspx.cs**

```
using foo;

namespace foo.foo2 {
    partial class bar2 {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            // can access foo.bar here in the source project but not once the DLL is compiled and copied to target
            var myVar = bar.myVar; // The name 'bar' does not exist in the current context
        }
    }
}
```

Why would this compile correctly in the source project, but prevent the target from building?

EDIT: Second project builds fine if I exclude myPage.aspx from the project. But I shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: See if your class is compiled with the same or lower version of .NET, otherwise you can't use it in your project.

Comment: Please try to clean, rebuild and add the reference again.

Comment: Have you tried using "Project Reference" rather than "Assembly Reference"? It might be that it's compiling your ASP.NET website before the dll is copied with your build script.

Comment: @Bringer128 - I removed the existing reference, readded it, and it seems to be working. Not sure why I hadn't done that previously...

Answer (score 1):

You have very likely an incorrect assembly referenced.

Make sure you use the correct physical assembly. Sometimes, a dead (old) version lies around (such as in the GAC) and this one is referenced rather than the believed new version.

Easiest way to confirm is to rename the assembly file to something else and reference the newly named assembly. `bar.myVar` should show up immediately.